# Error in script to count the number of occurrences

Tags: groovy

I am entirely new to Groovy scripting and need help.
I tried the following script to count the number of lines that has a specific text occurrence.

Error observed:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.io.File.eachline() is applicable for argument types: (Hemanth_v1$_run_closure2) values: [Hemanth_v1$_run_closure2@10f39d0]
Possible solutions: eachLine(groovy.lang.Closure), eachLine(int, groovy.lang.Closure), eachLine(java.lang.String, groovy.lang.Closure), eachFile(groovy.lang.Closure), eachLine(java.lang.String, int, groovy.lang.Closure), eachFile(groovy.io.FileType, groovy.lang.Closure)
```

Script:

```
def file = new File('C:\\NE\\header.txt');
count = 0
def data1= file.filterLine { line ->
    line.contains('smtpCus:');
}

//custom code by Hemanth
file.eachline { line, count ->
    if (line.contains('Received:')) {
        count++
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit this question and use the formatting tools to make it readable. This will also help you solve the problem. Also, the error you are getting is not from the script you show here. A [mcve] should match the errors.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with the script you've shown to us:

1. there is a typo in `file.eachline` - it should be `file.eachLine`
2. in the closure passed to `eachLine` you increment a local variable `count` so the outer `count` remains `0` after the execution.

Here is what your script should look like:

```
def file = new File('C:\\NE\\header.txt')
count = 0
def data1 = file.filterLine { line ->
    line.contains('smtpCus:')
}

//custom code by Hemanth
file.eachLine { line ->
    if (line.contains('Received:')) {
        count++
    }
}

println count
```

#### Reading file as `java.util.stream.Stream<T>`

There is also one thing worth mentioning if it comes to reading files in Groovy (and Java in general). If you work with a huge file it's a good practice to load this file using Java Stream API - [`Files.lines(path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-)

```
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths

long counter = Files.lines(Paths.get('C:\\NE\\header.txt'))
        .filter { line -> line.contains('Received:') }
        .count()

println counter
```

Answer (score 0):

Groovy methods use camel case. It should be eachLine() instead of eachline(). See if that helps!